# How do I connect to an existing database using the dynamodb wrapper?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the following Node wrapper to deal with a AWS database:

https://github.com/baseprime/dynamodb

This ReadMe seems to have instructions about how to define a model, create a table, etc. but I can't seem to find anything with regard to how to connect to an existing table. How do I do that using this wrapper?

Comment: https://github.com/baseprime/dynamodb#getting-started

Comment: where does it say how to connect to an existing database?

Comment: The entire readme gives examples of connecting to tables (there are no "databases" in dynamo). Why are you using an ORM? It seems as though you will be better served by using AWS SDK directly.

Comment: I mean can you point me to a line of code or something? The fact that I'm asking on Stackoverflow means that I already went through the ReadMe and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: You need to first define your model in js. Once you have done that, you can then query it as documented here: https://github.com/baseprime/dynamodb#query